# Is there a rule of thumb to choose a specific standardization method for regression?

Tags: regression, standardization, z-score, centering

I have been reading some resources and various techniques have been used to standardize the predictors in a regression model. Below, the first two are common approaches as far as I understand. The third one does not seem to be that common.

> (1) Centering the variables by subtracting the mean
>
> (2) Converting to zscore by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.
>
> (3) Dividing by two standard deviation to obtain a score between 0-1 ([resource](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/unpublished/standardizing.pdf))

I wonder if there is a rule of thumb to choose any of these methods? Should I try all options and then choose the one that gives me the best result?

Comment: I would not worry about this. They are all linear transformation, so substantively they will give the exact same results. The numbers will be different, but if you interpret the models correctly, you will arrive at the exact same conclusion.

Comment: @MaartenBuis you mean for example mean absolute error would not change much?

Comment: The fit remains unchanged, but I meant that also the conclusions drawn from the coefficients remain exactly unchanged. Compare method 2 and 3: It does not matter whether you say that 1 sd change in $x$ leads to $b$ change in $y$ or 2 sd change in $x$ leads to $2b$ change in $y$. Those are just different ways of saying the exact same thing.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I understand! One more related question, if I standardize the predictors, should I also standardize the outcome variable (which is a discrete number btw 1-8)?

Comment: There is no **need** to standardize any variable. I rarely standardize, as I am fortunate to work in a field where most or all variables have a directly interpretable scale. I may center my variables (subtract a meaningful value within the range of the data) when I include interaction terms, but that is as far as I will typically go. So only do so if it helps answer your question. If you are uncertain then in all likelihood it does not help, and you should not standardize.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Thanks sir! This rule counts even if that variable is the number of click times which could range from few to thousands?

Comment: For variables with such a large range I would typically consider a logarithmic transformation, as going from 1 to 2 clicks is typically more meaningfull than going 2,000 to 2,001 clicks. Notice that this is a non-linear transformtion, so it will change (hopefully improve) your model. Beware of 0s and negative numbers though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54341/discussion-between-renakre-and-maarten-buis).

Comment: @MaartenBuis this definitely makes sense. Sir, thanks for your help! Then, how I should treat the **0s** in this case? Also, let's say I have `Click_Site_1` and `Click_Site_2` columns, and I want to generate another column by summing up these two. In this case, should I log-transform these columns and then sum, or should I first sum them and then do the log-transformation? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a different question. Why not start a new question? I am going to sleep now, and won't be online tomorrow and traveling soon afterwards.

Comment: @MaartenBuis thanks sir, I will. Have a save travel!

Comment: Most software automatically performs standardization in order to fit the model in the first place.  The only reason you would recenter or rescale your variables therefore would be to help you interpret the output.